# Replace object with same object ID

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have two arrays. One is the old one. One is the new one. I'm using Angular 2+ / Ionic 2+. I'm able to loop through both arrays and filter the old one out to give me matching objects. Once it's matched I replace the old object with the new. However my what I want array isn't updating and I'm still getting the old array and the what I want.

Old

```
[
{itemID: 10, color: "blue"}
{itemID: 11, color: "red"}
{itemID: 12, color: "green"}
]
```

New

```
[
{itemID: 11, color: "purple", size: "small"}
{itemID: 12, color: "yellow", size: "large"}
]
```

What I want:

```
[
{itemID: 10, color: "blue"}
{itemID: 11, color: "purple", size: "small"}
{itemID: 12, color: "yellow", size: "large"}
]
```

Component.ts

```
console.log(this.oldArray, 'before')
              this.oldArray = this.oldArray.filter(resultOne => {

                 return this.newArray.map(resultTwo => {
                  if(resultOne.itemID == resultTwo.itemID){

                      return resultOne.itemID == resultTwo.itemID
                      }
                })
              })
              console.log(this.oldArray, 'after -- I'm getting the same as before')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just a little `reduce()` and `Object.assign()` will do this. Basically turn the arrays into objects, mix them, and turn them back to an array:

```js
var old_arr = [
  {itemID: 10, color: "blue"},
  {itemID: 11, color: "red"},
  {itemID: 12, color: "green"}
  ]

var new_arr = [
  {itemID: 11, color: "purple", size: "small"},
  {itemID: 12, color: "yellow", size: "large"}
  ]

var mixed = Object.assign( 
  old_arr.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc[curr.itemID] = curr, acc), {}),
  new_arr.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc[curr.itemID] = curr, acc), {})
)

var final  = Object.keys(mixed).map(key => (Object.assign({itemID: key},  mixed[key])))
console.log(final)
```